# JS string.replace() is url encoding string

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to replace a tag element in a URL using the code below. The actual replace works well but for some reason it's also changing the code to be URL encoded, for example `&` becomes `&amp;` - why is this?

```
let url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/Apple-iPhone-14-Pro-128/dp/B0BDJC5HW8?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_w=2pD6L&tag=gg99-33&blah=blah'

url = url.replace(/&tag=[\w-]+&/, '&tag=abc-123')

console.log(url)
```

Becomes:

```
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Apple-iPhone-14-Pro-128/dp/B0BDJC5HW8?_encoding=UTF8&amp;pd_rd_w=2pD6L&amp;tag=abc-123&amp;blah=blah
```

It should become:

```
https://www.amazon.co.uk/Apple-iPhone-14-Pro-128/dp/B0BDJC5HW8?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_w=2pD6L&tag=abc-123&blah=blah
```

Comment: How exactly are you checking the string value? The `.replace()` method definitely would not do that.

Comment: Please provide the actual code that reproduces your claim.

Comment: @Pointy checking with console.log

Comment: Well the code as posted is erroneous anyway, as it tries to reassign to the constant `url`. If that's fixed (with `let` instead), the code works and does not print HTML escapes in the console.

Comment: Also it doesn't change the string at all, because the `tag` parameter is at the end of the query string and it's not followed by `&` so the regex does not match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this string is a valid URL, you can construct a [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) object and change its search parameters, here is an example:

```js
const url = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/Apple-iPhone-14-Pro-128/dp/B0BDJC5HW8?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_w=2pD6L&tag=gg99-33'
const urlObj = new URL(url);
urlObj.searchParams.set('tag', 'abc-123');
const newURL = urlObj.toString();

console.log(newURL);
```